# Replace File Path Text After Specific String

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal, command

I have an audacity.cfg file in which I want to script the substitution of two plugin paths. The paths were previously different, so I need to inset the updated ones. I will provide one below.

First, I want to locate this text, which begins the line in question:

FFmpegLibPath

Next, I want to replace that entire line with:

FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib

That's it. It should not be so difficult, but it is. I have done lots of experimenting using sed and awk, but have not been able to get anything to work. While there are LOTS of examples of this online and in this forum, none of them have worked. They all produce errors relating to escape characters, as well as some random other things. I have spent hours experimenting and researching, but have not made any headway.

I realize that the slashes and spaces are likely causing issues, and I have spent considerable time attempting to solve this. I've tried all sorts of things, but as I've said, nothing works.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
I am running MacOS 10.10.5, and one of the things I saw in my research was using GNU sed, because some arguments do not work without it. While I am sure that would produce a better result, I cannot use it because my users would not have it. I think this is part of the reason why this is so difficult, because many of the solutions I have seen are utilizing arguments that I cannot use.

Comment: Add at least ONE example of your experiments... Otherwise, this is only _give me a solution_ type question... ;(

Comment: Fair enough - here is one of the last ones I tried: sed -e 's/:: FFmpegLibPath = [0-9]+$/:: FFmpegLibPath = 's#FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib#g' audacity.cfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything other fails, you always can use the old-school `ed` solution. :) :)

```
#!/bin/bash
{
printf 'H\n'
printf '/^FFmpegLibPath[ \t=]/\n'
printf '%s\n' c 'FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib' . w q
} | ed -s "/path/to/audacity.cfg" >/dev/null
```

The quotes, spaces are mandatory.

The above searching for the line starting with `FFmpegLibPath` and followed by `space` or `tab` or `=`. So it tries avoid collisions with similar prefixes like: `FFmpegLibPath2`.

If such collisions are not possible, the above could be simply written as:

```
ed -s "/path/to/audacity.cfg" >/dev/null <<'EOF'
H
/^FFmpegLibPath/
c
FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib
.
w
q
EOF
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' H '/^FFmpegLibPath/' c 'FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib' . w q |
ed -s "/path/to/audacity.cfg" >/dev/null
```

Comment: The first one worked! Amazing! However, when I tried the 3rd one, it would not recognize the destination file path. It spit out "No such file or directory."

Comment: There is only one instance of the items I am looking to replace in the config file, however I like to err on the side of caution when replacing things in a user's config files.

Comment: Then use the 1st one. The pattern is `FFmpegLibPath` followed by one of the `space`, `tab` or `=`.

Comment: Strike my earlier comment about the path not being found for the 3rd command - that was my mistake. I corrected my error and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much for these!

Comment: @SadMarvin enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the special character (forward slash) and assign it to a variable:

```
REPL=$(sed 's/[\/]/\\&/g' <<< "/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib")
```

`&` is sed's meta-character to represent the pattern that was matched.

```
sed -E "s/(FFmpegLibPath=).+/\1$REPL/" audacity.cfg
```

Option `-E` is used to support extended regular expressions

output:

```
etc
FFmpegLibPath=/Library/Application Support/audacity/libs/libavformat.55.dylib
etc
etc
```

If you preferred to maintain the updates in a separate text file:

```
cfg_update.txt
key_name1=value
key_name2=value
key_name3=value

# define delimiter
IFS=\=

cat cfg_update.txt | while read KEY VALUE; do
    sed -i -E "s/($KEY=).+/\1$VALUE/" audacity.cfg
done
```

option `-i` is used to edit file in place

Finally, be sure to make a backup before your tests, good luck!

Comment: Would I then need to make this part of a larger expression or script in order to accommodate the multiple lines?

Comment: If there are more than a few updates, you may want to maintain them in a text file. Example as shown in the answer (can't construct scripts in the comment)

Comment: In this particular instance there are only two changes, but it is certainly possible that this could be useful in the future for something that requires larger changes like that. I used a similar cat script with a Firefox config file update project, but all I needed it to do was put the new lines at the end, and Firefox will prune and reorder the file when it is first opened.